# JPanel won't repaint when assigned a new subclass

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I ran into a problem where no matter what I do my JPanel won't repaint. I was using the following method to create a connect four game board and dynamically change the color of the circles as the play progresses, but I've simplified it into a test class which has the same issue.

I decided to use a state pattern design for each of the circles. The following is the code for the classes so it knows which color to print which are JPanel children classes.

```
public class GridCircle extends JPanel
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

    }

}

public class WhiteGridCircle extends GridCircle 
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(5, 5, 80, 80);

    }

}

public class RedGridCircle extends GridCircle
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(5, 5, 80, 80);

    }

}
```

The following is a test class where I attempt to change the class of a JPanel in the main method to see if it would change the color that is painted (which fails).

```
public class test extends JFrame 
{

    static JPanel testPanel = new WhiteGridCircle();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new test();
        testPanel = new RedGridCircle();
        testPanel.revalidate();
        testPanel.repaint();
    }

    test()
    {
        this.add(testPanel);
        this.setSize(150,150);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I can't figure out why the panel wouldn't repaint no matter what I've tried. From what I understand repaint() has no guarantee to call a the paint method but I see no reason it shouldn't when theres nothing else going on.

Comment: You're changing the object a certain variable refers to, but this won't magically have an effect on the displayed object. You need to change the JPanel *object* held by the GUI. This gets down to the basic difference between an *object* and a *variable*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because instance you created and added `this.add(testPanel);` is still `new WhiteGridCircle()`.

You changed instance but the original one added to JFrame remains in the frame.

To change call `this.getContentPane().add(testPanel);` after instantiating RedGridCircle and before `revalidate()` call.

Comment: I had to adapt this to my main program since I had everything in an array and couldn't just add one to the end. I ended up needing to reset the entire outer JPanel and readd everything but it worked so thanks :)